# HTML: How to make input type list only accept a list choice?

Tags: html, validation, input

I use the following code to provide a multiple choice in an HTML form:

```
Estado: <input list="states"><datalist id="states">
<option value="Pendiente">Pendiente</option>
<option value="Frenada">Frenada</option>
<option value="Finalizada">Finalizada</option>
</datalist><br>
```

The thing is, I can still type in the resulting input box in the browser. I want to block the user from typing, so that it's only choice is to select from the list. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this to prevent user from typing and make a choice from available options.

```
<select name="states">
<option name="Pendiente">Pendiente</option>
<option name="Frenada">Frenada</option>
<option name="Finalizada">Finalizada</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Did not work. It created a select box beside a normal input text box. Further more when I submit the form I cannot (or I don't know how) to read the value of the selection.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to let the user type in the input box, then don't use `<input>`;
use `<select></select>` instead

```
Estado:&nbsp;
<select name="states">
  <option value="Pendiente">Pendiente</option>
  <option value="Frenada">Frenada</option>
  <option value="Finalizada">Finalizada</option>
</select><br>
```